# swift command to test openstack object storage

Tags: openstack-swift

i have error when i execute **swift -A http://xxx.xxx.x.x:5000/v2.0 -U service:swift -K swift -V 2.0 stat**
outputlike this
**Auth GET failed: http://xxx.xxx.x.x:5000/v2.0/tokens 500 Internal Server Error**
 maybe any solution for me !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

koolhead17
I have tried to execute sudo `swift-init main start`

result IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/etc/swift/object.ring.gz'

and then when i execute  sudo swift-init rest start

result  IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/etc/swift/object.ring.gz'

maybe...any solution for me? :)

Comment: it means your configuration needs a check again. kindly check your configuration file http://docs.openstack.org/developer/swift/development_saio.html will be good place to check the configs.

Answer (score 1):

```
swift -v -V 2.0 -A http://127.0.0.1:5000/v2.0/ -U service:swift -K swift stat
```

Let me know what you get after executing this. Also make sure all your swift related services are running. You can start all of them at once using.

```
sudo swift-init main start
sudo swift-init rest start
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Elvis Jon Freddy Sitinjak, you need to copy the object.ring.gz from your proxy node to all the storage nodes.

Answer (score 0):

to run your swift environment, use following command: `swift-init all restart`