# Auth GET failed: 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: openstack-swift

i have problem with swift..when i execute `swift -V 2.0 -A http://xxx.xxx.x.xx:5000/v2.0/ -U cookbook:demo -K openstack stat`

and then this is output

Auth GET failed: http://xxx.xxx.x.xx:5000/v2.0/tokens 500 Internal Server Error

any solution for me? :)

Comment: The logs at /var/log/swift/ might give you a clue of what's going on.

Comment: Is all your swift services running. Please double check if the authentication your using is correct.

Comment: @elvis were you ale to resolve it?

Comment: seems like you asked the same question twice [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20281713/swift-command-to-test-openstack-object-storage][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20281713/swift-command-to-test-openstack-object-storage

Answer (score 0):

I hit this error while execute 'swift list'. 
Error: Account GET failed ... 503 Internal Server Error (first 60 chars of response)...

On swift storage node, check log '/var/log/swift/account-server.log', and get a piece of error message:**[Errno 13] Permission denied '/srv/node/sdb1/accounts'**

According to the error message, I found the root cause is that, on swift storage node, the swift user doesn't have permission on directory '/srv/node/'. Grant permission with CMD: ***chown -R swift:swift /srv/node***
And the problem is solved. Hope this helpful.